# PHP upload file to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file in mysql database but when I click the "Upload" button I  get my plain PHP code returned. I have no idea where my problem is..
Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
      ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="upload" action="./upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the PHP code for uploading:

```
<? php

if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['file']['size'] > 0)
{
    $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];

    $parser = fopen($file_tmp, 'r');
    $content = fread($parser, filesize($file_tmp));
    $content = addslashes($content);
    fclose($parser);

    if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $file_name = addcslashes($file_name);
    }

    $user = "root";
    $host = "localhost";
    $pass = "";
    $db   = "filemeup";

    try 
    {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;", $user, $pass);
    } 
    catch(PDOException $e) 
    {
        echo "Error: ".$e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
    $conn->query("SET NAMES utf8");

    $query="INSERT INTO files (name, size, type, content)"."VALUES (:name, :size, :type, :content) ";
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $file_name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':size', $file_size);
    $stmt->bindParam(':type', $file_type);
    $stmt->bindParam(':content', $content);
    $stmt->execute();
?>
```

Comment: I don't know, but it may be from your php tag being `<? php` instead of `<?php`

Comment: Then it gives me the following error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\filemeup\upload.php on line 43`

Comment: First, that's a good sign, it means that you code is actually run. Second, that error is normally from when you're missing the closing bracket of some sort. In this case, you're missing the closing bracket of `if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['file']['size'] > 0)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your opening PHP tag to `<?php` and add a curly bracket to the end of your file. (Missing the closing bracket for your `if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['file']['size'] > 0)`)

I tried it and it definitely doesn't work in Google Chrome although it's hidden.

Comment: What a stupid mistake, sorry for bothering :( Nevertheless, it doesn't upload to the database..

Comment: No worries. If you add a new question regarding it not uploading and add a link here, I could probably help you :)